# Confusion in Dart's async await

Tags: dart

I have a confusion in understanding Dart's async/await functionality. Most tutorials use the following example:

```
Future<String> createOrderMessage() async {
  var order = await fetchUserOrder();
  return 'Your order is: $order';
}

Future<String> fetchUserOrder() =>
    // Imagine that this function is
    // more complex and slow.
    Future.delayed(
      const Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => 'Large Latte',
    );

Future<void> main() async {
  print('Fetching user order...');
  print(await createOrderMessage());
}
```

I understand that the fetchUserOrder function returns a Future. Anyone who calls this function will immediately get a Future object as a result but this Future object may not have the real result value at that time. It will be filled up in "future".

Now, the createOrderMessage function calls: await fetchUserOrder(); This means, the control will wait till fetchUserOrder() returns a completed/non-empty Future. Am I right here? Is this what await does?

If that is correct, it means, the createOrderMessage function is essentially synchronous now because it won't return until the Future returned by fetchUserOrder is filled. Thus, the order variable in this function is initialized with a completed Future. Then why does this function need the "async" keyword in its function declaration? What does it signify?

Second confusion is if Dart is single threaded, when and how exactly is an async function executed? If I invoke multiple method calls that return Futures like this without await:

```
...
Future<A> fa = getA();
Future<B> fb = getB();
Future<C> fa = getC();
...
```

Will the functions getA, getB, and getC be executed sequentially in the background or they will be executed "in parallel" somehow?

Comment: `await` is not blocking. `await` always *yields*.  It's really syntactic sugar for registering a `.then()` callback on the `Future` and returning from the function.  As for your second question: it depends on how `getA`, `getB`, and `getC` are implemented.  They could run in parallel, such as if they run in separate Dart isolates or in separate threads in the Dart VM/runtime.

Comment: Well, from the above code, the control stops at await until the called function returns a value. That means, await is actually blocking the execution from proceeding to the next statement. No?

Comment: No.  Blocking means execution of the entire thread stops. `await` returns from the function and goes back to the event loop. `await` doesn't actually wait; it registers a callback.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, the createOrderMessage function calls: await fetchUserOrder(); This means, the control will wait till fetchUserOrder() returns a completed/non-empty Future. Am I right here? Is this what await does?

Yes. the `await` keyword means you get the completed `T` instead of `Future<T>` in return. So:

```dart
var a = fetchUserOrder(); // Type of a: Future<String>
var b = await fetchUserOrder(); // Type of b: String
```

When you use await, you tell the code to **await the completion of the process** and get the actual result. But without await, the stream is in the future and is in process until you await it somewhere else.

> why does this function need the "async" keyword in its function declaration?

It's a rule to specify long-running functions. So when a function awaits for a long running process to complete, the function itself is also a long-running process. Why? Because it's waiting for another one to complete.

Therefore, you need to specify `async` for that as well. When another function is calling this one, it also knows this one might be long-running.

In short, every **awaitable** function needs to be in an `async` function.

> Second confusion is if Dart is single threaded, when and how exactly is an async function executed?

You're mixing the concept of parallelism with asynchronous. An async process does not have to be done in multi thread.
Async processes can be one one at time, but in a different order in compare to synchronous code.
Take a look at [this article](https://thecodest.co/blog/asynchronous-and-single-threaded-javascript-meet-the-event-loop/#:%7E:text=to%20be%20completed.-,Synchronous,-and%20Asynchronous%20in) which explains asynchronous in a single thread.

Comment: If "the await keyword means you get the completed T instead of Future<T> in return" then why is the return type of the createOrderMessage function Future<String> instead of just String? The function code uses await fetchUserOrder(), so it already has the String value and not Future<String>, right? The return type of the createOrderMessage function should be String then, no?

var order = await fetchUserOrder();
  return 'Your order is: $order';

Comment: So, mentally, I can replace "async" with "longrunning" to understand it better? And if a function is "longrunning" then its return type will automatically be a Future<T> (even though the code inside the function returns a T)? Am I right?

Comment: Well the return type of function is a proccess and not a typed result. Thus, the type should not be String. Instead Future<String> allows the usage of `await` for the compiler. Though, it's not really needed to be like that. That's how dartlang devs decided.

Comment: If a function actually returned something that could be awaited on, yes. It should be Future. But void functions aren't forced to do such AFAIK. But use the word "asynchronous" instead of "long-running". Although you're not wrong by using that, but you're not covering all usages of async with the term "long-running"

Answer (score 0):

> Now, the createOrderMessage function calls: await fetchUserOrder(); This means, the control will wait till fetchUserOrder() returns a completed/non-empty Future. Am I right here? Is this what await does?
>
> If that is correct, it means, the createOrderMessage function is essentially synchronous now because it won't return until the Future returned by fetchUserOrder is filled. Thus, the order variable in this function is initialized with a completed Future.

`await` allows asynchronous functions to have the *appearance* of synchronous functions by allowing asynchronous code to be structured very similarly to synchronous code.  In your example, it's syntactic sugar for registering a `Future.then()` callback and immediately returning:

```dart
Future<String> createOrderMessage() {
  var future = fetchUserOrder().then((order) {
    return 'Your order is: $order';
  });
  return future;
}
```

`await` defers execution of the rest of *that function*; it does not wait and block execution of your entire thread.  Your program will continue running its event loop, possibly allowing other asynchronous operations to make progress.

> Will the functions getA, getB, and getC be executed sequentially in the background or they will be executed "in parallel" somehow?

As I mentioned in comments, it depends on how `getA`, `getB`, and `getC` are implemented. They could run in parallel, such as if they run in separate Dart isolates or in separate threads in the Dart VM/runtime.

Comment: In your code, the flow of execution stops on the call to fetchUserOrder() until a value is returned and only after the execution of the next line i.e. return future; happens. Is that correct? If so, then what exactly is happening asynchronously here? Whichever thread (or whatever it is called in dart) executed the first line, stops/waits for the return value and then executes the second line. Which part of this code is executed by the "event thread"? Are there two different threads executing different pieces of this code?

Comment: No, execution calls `fetchUserOrder` and the `createOrderMessage` returns a `Future` to its caller immediately.  When the value is ready, the `Future`'s `.then` callback will be called.  It's asynchronous because the callback is not fired *immediately* but at some point in the future.

Comment: OK, I understand now that fetchUserOrder returns immediately but it is the part inside then, that blocks until the value is ready.   

So effectively, the flow of execution is blocked before executing "return future;" statement until future is ready with a value. Is that correct? Isn't that blocking?

Comment: @Priyshrm No.  As I've stated already, `createOrderMessage` returns the `Future` object.  The `Future` has no result yet.  The event loop will continue running normally, possibly dispatching other asynchronous callbacks.  When the `Future` does have a result, the event loop will invoke its completion callback.

Comment: And to clarify about the part inside the `.then()`: it creates a function, but that function will not be executed immediately.  It will be called sometime later once the result is available.